# How to add attribute value to root element when using for XML path?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this SQL and it works:

```
set nocount on 

DECLARE
    @OrderID VARCHAR(200) = '13095314100';

declare @eOrder Table
(
  colOrderId  varchar(20),
  colDeliveryCountryCode varchar(20)
 )

insert into @eOrder values ('13095314100', 'SE')


SELECT 
    'name'  AS 'Val/@n', Sender.name AS Val

FROM @eOrder E
  inner join 
    (
       select  '12345' SenderID,     'KappAhl Sverige AB' "name",  'Idrottsvägen 14' "address1",   null address2,       '431 24' ZipCode,   'MÖLNDAL' City, 'SE' Country,  '010-138 87 11' phone
       union
       select  '12345',          'KappAhl Shop Online',       'c/o KappAhl OY',             'Unikkotie 3 C',    '01300'     ,  'VANTAA',        'PL',        '0753 267 881'    
    ) Sender
    on E.colDeliveryCountryCode = Sender.Country

WHERE colOrderId = @OrderID
FOR XML PATH('Sender');
```

I get this output as expected:

```
<Sender><Val n="name">KappAhl Sverige AB</Val></Sender>
```

But how do I add `SenderID` as an attribute to my `Sender` tag?

Wanted XML output:

```
<Sender SenderID="12345" ><Val n="name">KappAhl Sverige AB</Val></Sender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Sender.SenderID as '@SenderID'` to your select:

```
SELECT Sender.SenderID as '@SenderID',
    'name'  AS 'Val/@n', Sender.name AS Val
```

Result:

[image]